# How to combine CASE and EXISTS in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      "Teaching"
    WHERE 
      "Teaching".student_idn = "Student".idn
  ) THEN 'Teaching Assistant' ELSE 'Student' END AS "Category" 
FROM 
  "Student"
```

How can this be written in SQL Alchemy? I was able to figure out how `CASE` can be done. But its getting complex when we need `EXISTS`

Comment: Plenty of ways. There's the core construct [`exists()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists), the [Query API equivalent](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) and the [shortcut from relationship properties](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists). So the answer depends on your existing code.

Comment: Possibly even look at a hybrid property and filter on that... (depending what level you're using sqla at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach works:

```python
sub = session.query(Teaching).filter(Teaching.columns.student_idn == Student.columns.idn)

query = session.query(Student.columns.name, case([(sub.exists(), "Teaching Assistant")], else_ = "Student")
)
```

Probably there are better ways.